# Is there such a dictionary or anything similar in Ukrainian? Ozdic.com

Tags: resource-request

I've stumbled upon a great, mind breaking dictionary in English. It provides you with all the words connected to a word you enter.

Here's an example: http://ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/proposal

As you can see, there are all kinds of words connected to a word `proposal` in this example. Adjectives, verbs, nouns, prepositions, phrases that you can use in a sentence with it. In addition, there are sentence examples.

Is there anything at least recalling such thing in Ukrainian?

Comment: http://lang.org.ua/uk/models/

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka дякую, дуже цікаво. Я правильно розумію, що в онлайн не працює і треба завантажувати?

Comment: Тональний мережевий (останній у списку), перші два - завантажувати.

Answer (score 4):

Not an online dictionary, but at least something that exists in a paper format: [Словник сполучуваності слів української мови: Найуживаніша лексика](http://liber.onu.edu.ua/opacunicode/index.php?url=/notices/index/IdNotice:160417/Source:default) (Сахно І. П., Сахно М. М. - 1999).

Here's an extract from it found in [this article](http://enpuir.npu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/16129/1/Hoshovs%27ka.pdf):

> **віра**: тверда, глибока, непохитна, наївна, сліпа віра; віра в людину, свої сили, самого себе, справедливість, успіх, торжество розуму; вселити, втратити віру в кого-що-небудь; не йняти віри [своїм, власним] вухам, очам, словам; підривати, підточувати, руйнувати, похитнути чиюсь віру в кого-що-небудь; перейнятися, пройнятися вірою в кого-що-небудь; робити що-небудь без віри, з вірою в успіх; сприйняти що-небудь, не приймати нічого на віру.

As one can see, it seems to be a pretty good dictionary. Not sure where one could buy it though.

Comment: It is similar indeed, but it would most certainly not be very effective and comfortable to use. I'd love to have such a dictionary online. And much more of them...